# Using different comparison operators based on conditional logic

Tags: c#, operators, conditional-statements

I don't want to duplicate tons of code in my Application so I would like to do the following.

```
// PSEUDO CODE

if (next == true) {operator = "<=";}
else {operator = ">=";}

// Should use "row >= nowRow" or "row <= nowRow" to avoid having repeated code
if (row.Count operator nowRow) { ... }
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Sorry it should read "Substitution"

Comment: I'd suggest reading up on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.icomparable?view=netframework-4.8 . And likely use a `Dictionary` where the value is a `Func`.

Comment: you can edit your question to fix obvious spelling mistakes

Answer (score 1):

you can use lambda expressions to do something like

```
var compare = next ? (Func<int,int,bool>)((l, r) => l <= r) : ((l, r) => l >= r);

if(compare(rowDat.Count, nowRow))
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can assign a function to a variable of a delegate type. 
In your case, [`Func<T1,T2,TResult> Delegate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.func-3?view=netframework-4.8) is appropriate.

```
Func<int, int, bool> func = (x,y) => x <= y;
Console.WriteLine(func(1,2));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Ken and Lesiak.  I never even thought of a delegate, it's been a while for me. I really appreciate such swift help

Comment: Hi Lesiak, I could not get it to compile on VS2019.  It says it needs a comma after the "(x,y)". however it did not work after that either. I cut and pasted it right from the web page too.  I used Keith's answer and it worked well.  Sorry for the spelling; my fingers are too fat plus I have Carpel Tunnel syndrome.

Comment: It is more of a compiler version than ide version question (although support for delegates and lambdas was available for quite a while). Here is running example on .NET 4.7 https://dotnetfiddle.net/EwDVIB
You'd need to post your exact code and compiler version if you need more help with this.

Comment: This version did work in my VS2019 .NET4.7.2 API just now as a matter of fact..  The only thing I can think of is that when I copied it from the other webpage, from Lesiak, it may have had a bad or corrupted piece of data in it that was invisible.